# Randomizar resultados com PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, random

Eu tenho uma estrutura assim (que eu criei):

```
<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_1")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_2")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_3")?>
</div>
<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_4")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_5")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_6")?>
</div>
<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_7")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_8")?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_9")?>
</div>
```

Eu preciso randomizar os resultados de 1 a 9 para que todos os banners ao dar um refresh recebam uma variável com um número aleatório e que não se repita.

Alguma coisa do tipo: `meubanner_$numeroaleatorio`. Não sei exatamente com que este processo esta relacionado, loop ou outra coisa.

Comment: Oi Marcos, editei as tags da pergunta e parti da suposição que é o `do_shortcode` do WordPress. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Bom, vasculhei a web e não há outras instâncias da função `do_shortcode()`. Só se for uma função personalizada sua, e se for esse o caso, ajuste as tags e me dê um toque para adaptar minha resposta.

Comment: Pode se utilizar da função rand(numero_inicial,numero_final), que é nativo <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".rand(0,10)); ?>. E claro você economiza em linhas de códigos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para não haver repetição use esse código:

***Exemplo Online:*** [**Ideone**](https://ideone.com/0p0HfH)

```
<?php
    $array_number = array();
    for($i = 1; $i <=9; $i++)
    {
        $value = rand(1,9);
        while (in_array($value, $array_number))
        {
            $value = rand(1,9);
        }
        $array_number[$i - 1] = $value;
    }
    function do_shortcode($value){
        return $value;
    }
?>

<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[0]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[1]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[2]);?>
</div>
<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[3]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[4]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[5]);?>
</div>
<div class="banners">
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[6]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[7]);?>
     <?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$array_number[8]);?>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs:** *a function* `do_sortcode` *colocado no meu exemplo é simplesmente para teste.*

Comment: Esta solução é perfeita e exatamente o que preciso pois não existe a necessidade de ficar dentro de um loop ou qualquer elemento que individualize a execução a um bloco específico do código, tipo você pode colocar isso em qualquer lugar.

Answer (score 11):

Outra forma de fazer não extamente 'aleatória' é pegar o array dos banners e chamar [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.shuffle.php) para embaralha-lo. Depois pode criar uma função que remove os itens do array para evitar a repetição utilizando [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-shift.php). O simbolo `&` significa que a variável é passada como referência ou seja a cada chamada da função um item será removido de `$banners`

```
function exibirBanner(&$arr){
   if(!empty($arr)) return array_shift($arr);
}

$banners = array('banner1', 'banner2', 'banner3', 'banner4');
shuffle($banners);


echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
echo exibirBanner($banners) .'<br>';
```

**[Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/pjt5-98e8)**

Comment: Também é uma solução visto que a quantidade de banners é exata e pode ser por sorteio. Obrigado pela solução apresentada.

Answer (score 6):

Não seria isso?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".rand(1,9))?>
```

Ou melhor, pra não repetir, use a função `array_rand()`. Crie um vetor com os número de 1-9 e randomize, depois com um laço crie a estrutura que você deseja.

```
$vetor = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9');
$random = array_rand($vetor, 9);

for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++) {
   echo do_shortcode("meubanner_".$vetor[$random[$i]]);
}
```

Comment: Essa era a resposta que eu estava procurando encontrar em meio a tantas possíveis soluções. Parabéns!

Answer (score 6):

Em vez de fazer 9 shortcodes `[meubanner_*]` no WordPress, isso pode ser resolvido com um só: `[meubanner]`. Adaptei a [solução da Maria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31161/randomizar-resultados-com-php/31170#31170) para fazer o número randômico sem repetição. E fiz um plugin [OOP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/orienta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-a-objetos/info) para poder armazenar a array de números já selecionados.

Cada vez que o `do_shortcode("[meubanner]")` for chamado, o Shortcode vai executar o método `random()` que retorna um número randômico que **não esteja** na array `$num_selecionados`. Antes de retornar, o novo número é armazenado na array evitando sua repetição.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: (SOPT) Nove shortcodes randomicos
 * Plugin URI:  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31205/201
 * Author:      brasofilo 
*/

add_action(
    'plugins_loaded',
    array ( SOPT_31161_Shortcode::get_instance(), 'plugin_setup' )
);

class SOPT_31161_Shortcode
{
    protected static $instance = NULL;
    public $num_selecionados = array();

    /**
     * Constructor. Deixado publico e vazio intencionalmente.
     */
    public function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Acessar a instancia de trabalho deste plugin.
     * @return  object of this class
     */
    public static function get_instance()
    {
        NULL === self::$instance and self::$instance = new self;
        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Usado para iniciar os trabalhos normais do plugin.
     */
    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        add_shortcode( 'meubanner', array( $this, 'shortcode' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Shortcode [meubanner]
     */
    public function shortcode( $atts, $content )
    {
        $html = sprintf(
            '<h3>Banner #%s</h3>',
            $this->random()
        );
        return $html;
    }

    /**
     * Retorna um número randomico de 1 a 9 que não esteja na array $num_selecionados
     * Inspirado em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31170/201
     */
    public function random()
    {
        $value = rand( 1, 9 );

        // Executar até achar um número que não esteja em $num_selecionados
        while( in_array( $value, $this->num_selecionados ) )
            $value = rand( 1, 9 );

        // Adicionar novo número a array
        $this->num_selecionados[] = $value;

        return $value;
    }

    /**
     * Imprimir 3 divs contendo 3 shortcodes cada
     * Modo de uso: <?php SOPT_31161_Shortcode::get_instance()->print_banners(); ?>
     */
    public function print_banners()
    {
        for( $i = 1; $i <=3; $i++ )
        {
            echo '<div class="banners">';
            for( $j = 1; $j <=3; $j++ )
                echo do_shortcode( "[meubanner]");
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

E no template ou widget, chamar a função que imprime 3 divs contendo 3 shortcodes cada com:

```
<?php 
    if( class_exists( 'SOPT_31161_Shortcode' ) {
        SOPT_31161_Shortcode::get_instance()->print_banners();
    }
?>
```

O resultado é:

> [image: ss]

Comment: E nesse código você já adicionou para ser mostrado três de cada vez conforme a necessidade apresentada?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta incorporando a criação dos divs dentro da classe e mostrando o resultado obtido.

Answer (score 5):

Em php é o que eles disseram.... `rand(1,9)`
Como se trata de banner, algo como uma imagem... não seria melhor trazer por js?

```
var numero = Array();

//Populando o array de 0 a 8
for (i=0; i < 9; i++) { 
    numero[i] = i;
}

//Sorteando
numero.sort(randOrd);

//Somente escreve o resultado, adaptável pra sua necessidade
for (i=0; i < 9; i++) { 
    document.write('<br>'+numero[i]); 
}

//Faz manipulação algébrica pra puxar o próximo resultado
function randOrd() { 
    return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

você pode fazer isso utilizando a função Rand() do php. segue exemplo de utilização:

```
 int rand ( int $min , int $max )
```

Depois é só concatenar com a string.

Answer (score 4):

Deixe-me propor outra possibilidade, sem loops manuais:

```
$ids = range( 1, 9 ); // Define o intervalo

shuffle( $ids ); // Embaralha

$ids = array_chunk( $ids, 3 ); // Divide em blocos de 3

// Monta a estrutura

array_walk(

    $ids,

    function( $ids ) {

        echo "<div class=\"banners\">\n\n    ";

        array_map( 'do_shortcode', $ids );

        echo "\n</div>\n\n";

    }
);
```

E a função **do_shortcode**, contanto que possa ser localizada no escopo da Aplicação, fará o que tem de fazer, seja lá o que for.

A título de exemplo, uma implementação simples como essa:

```
function do_shortcode( $id ) { printf( "meubanner_%d\n    ", $id ); }
```

**Dentro do código anterior**, mostraria algo como (já que é aleatório):

```
<div class="banners">

    meubanner_3
    meubanner_9
    meubanner_2

</div>

<div class="banners">

    meubanner_1
    meubanner_8
    meubanner_6

</div>

<div class="banners">

    meubanner_7
    meubanner_4
    meubanner_5

</div>
```