# Pegar valor aleatório mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random

Gostaria de saber alguma forma de pegar algum valor aleatório do MySQL sem repetir, eu estou usando esta linha:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND()");`

mas ele repete bastante os usuários que eu mostro na tela, e se possível, se passar pelo usuário, pelo **id** ele não mostre mais, algo desta forma.

Comment: Aí não é aleatório ;).

Comment: [Randomizar resultados com PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31178/91)

Comment: @rray, eu pensei em algo como tinder, que exibe pessoas diferentes... o rand até funciona mas não como eu imaginei...

Answer (score 2):

O Método RAND() do MYSQL suporta SEED que força a gera um número aleatório diferente para cada SEED o que fará com que tenha uma ordem diferente para cada uma delas, mas a mesma ordem para um mesmo SEED.

Você pode usar os segundos do dia para um SEED adequando.

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY RAND(%d)", time()%(24*60*60) );
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

Para usar minutos use time()%(24*60)

Este código fará com a ordem sempre se repita no mesmo instante do dia.

Em que isso ajuda?
Bom, fica mais fácil por exemplo, mostrar uma lista aleatoriamente para alguém e manter essa lista pelo tempo que desejar. 
Supondo que para cada usuário você queira mostrar uma lista aleatoria diferente, mas quer que a lista seja a mesma enquanto o usuario estiver logado. Você pode usar o id desse usuario juntamente com alguma informação que sempre mude como o numero do dia para o seed e desta forma durante um periodo qualquer terá uma lista aleatoria identica sempre que executar a consulta, evitando ter de codificar isso na linguagem.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar pegar todos os usuários de uma vez.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM users LIMIT X ORDER BY RAND()
```

Onde o X é a quantidade de usuários