# Criar/Usar shortcodes no php

Tags: php, shortcode

Queria saber como posso criar shortcodes no php puro (não usarei wordpress e seus plugins).

**Não pretendo usar funções no php para esse fim.** Gostaria de criar uma estrutura, em que eu pudesse dar um nome a um **trecho de código** em php e quando o chamasse na página ele me retornaria todo o conteúdo anteriormente definido.

Por exemplo, na área administrativa do site seria assim:

**Nome do shortcode: pt-so**

Conteúdo do shortcode supracitado:

```
<?php 
   // Aqui poderia usar qualquer coisa no php, usar while, functions, etc.
   echo "<p>Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português!</p>";
?>
```

Arquivo php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Chamando o shortcode -->
    [pt-so]
</body>
</html>
```

No código php onde está localizada a chamada ao shortcode, ele imprimirá o parágrafo com as boas vindas. Como farei um sistema com área administrativa, isso seria um dos recursos que o mesmo sistema teria. Só quero entender como posso fazer essa chamada de um shortcode na página do meu sistema/site que ficará visível ao público.

> Obs.: Tentei extrair a resposta nessa pergunta, mas não consegui
>
> [Randomizar resultados com PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31161/randomizar-resultados-com-php)

Comment: +1 por não usar o wordpress, você pode fazer com includes/requires ou funções

Comment: Eu até estava supondo isso, mas o que quero entender é como aquela chamada do shortcode na minha página vai chamar a definição do código lá no sistema.

Comment: resumindo, vc quer criar o seu próprio mecanismo de template?

Comment: Olha, acho que é isso mesmo. Isso fica muito difícil? porque eu poderia alterar, excluir tal shortcode se eu quisesse, e lógico, poderia adicionar tantos quanto eu quisesse tbm

Comment: é uma boa pergunta, eu não saberia como fazer o php varrer todo o html procurando pelos shortcotes especificos para realizar o processo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não está muito claro sobre se isso poderia ser feito com um parser em PHP, mas se for isso, aqui vai um exemplo simples.

## Exemplo

Arquivo **teste.php**

```
function CompileTemplate($file, $parse)
{
    return str_replace(array_keys($parse), $parse, file_get_contents($file));
}

/*
Nesse array, o relacionamento entre o short code e o seu par.
*/
$parse = array(
    '[pt-so]' => 'Foo bar '.time();
);

echo CompileTemplate('compile-template.html', $parse);
```

O arquivo HTML. Vamos chamá-lo de **compile-template.html**.

Note que nesse arquivo, não há nada em PHP conforme elucidado na pergunta.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Chamando o shortcode -->
    [pt-so]
</body>
</html>
```

Para testar, apenas crie os dois arquivos num mesmo diretório e execute **teste.php**.

## Burlando o template

Experimente tentar usar um código PHP no template (*compile-template.html*).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Chamando o shortcode -->
    [pt-so]
    PHP: <?php echo time();?>
</body>
</html>
```

Veja que o PHP não será interpretado. Pois tudo é tratado como texto puro.

Todas as execuções em PHP seriam chamdas dentro da função `CompileTemplate()`.

Note que os scripts acima são meramente didáticos.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, tanto seu shortcode "pt-so" quanto o arquivo que chama o shortcode são arquivos php do seu sistema. Tendo isso em vista, o que você está pedindo é apenas uma forma de colar o códigos dos seus arquivos que representam shortcodes (por exemplo o "pt-so"), dentro de outros arquivos php.

Segue um exemplo de como você poderia fazer isso:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Chamando o shortcode -->
    <?php require_once "pt-so.php";?>
</body>
</html>
```

onde "pt-so.php" é o arquivo php que contém seu shortcode:

```
<?php
    // Aqui poderia usar qualquer coisa no php, usar while, functions, etc.
    echo "<p>Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português!</p>";
?>
```

No código acima, `<?php require_once "pt-so.php";?>` corresponde à chamada ao shortcode, ou seja, é a minha versão do `[pt-so]` do Wordpress.

Reconheço que, comparado com a forma como o Wordpress faz os shortcodes, isso parece bastante desagradável, mas isso ocorre porque o Wordpress executa um novo nível de interpretação encima de seu código: ele lê seu código PHP e gera um novo código PHP, o qual será utilizado para responder seus usuários.

Answer (score -1):

Crie uma estrutura case em um arquivo chamado shortcodes.php e inclua via include no header do sistema/site.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
    //sem linguagem é PT
    if (!isset($lang)){
        $lang="pt";
    }

    switch($lang){
        case "pt":

        $langSo = "<p>Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português!</p>";

    break;

        case "es":

        $langSo = "<p>Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Spanish!</p>";

    break;

    }
?>



<html>
<head>
    <title>Teste</title>

    <?php include('shortcodes.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Chamando o shortcode -->


    <?php 
    $lang = 'es';

    echo $langSo;  //Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Spanish!

    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: denis, isso não faz o que eu pedi. Eu quero que a chamada "[pt-so]" chame o conteúdo php de um shortcode definido

Comment: Eu fiz um exemplo baseado na necessidade. Que eu saiba, shortcode é uma função definida do Wordpress.

Comment: então Denis, eu uso o wordpress e sei que lá se usam shortcodes. Porém isso não me soa como "propriedade do wordpress" até porque isso é possível fazer em outras linguagens. Como o wordpress é feito em php e lá são usados os shortcodes, optei por usar os shortcodes sem usar o wordpress. Nesse seu exemplo você está usando comandos php, como o "echo" dentro da página e não é isso o que desejo.