# Selects randômicos com PHP e MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, back-end

Existem algum modo de fazer selects randômicos com php e mysql.

Exemplo:

1- Tenho a tabela carreta_furacao:

```
id----nome
 1----Fofão
 2----Capitão América
 3----Popeye
 4----Mickey
 5----Palhaço
```

2- No PHP faço um select randômico*

3- Retorna o id 1 e 3

4- Clico no botão carregar mais, e isso ativa outro select randômico, dessa vez irão surgir outros 2 dados exceto os com id 1 e 3 porque esses já foram.

5- O ciclo se repete até todos os itens serem listados

*Encontrei diversos modos de fazer selects randômicos na web, mas ainda não sei qual é o melhor, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Obs: Só pra deixar claro, sei fazer selects e afins, o problema é como fazer essa "função randômica que não repete id's"

Comment: Se vc quer eliminar alguns ai não é randomico :P. vc pode pegar o array jogar na sessão e ir removendo os itens de do inicio em pares. Esse problema é parecido com: [Randomizar resultados com PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31161/91). Carreta furacão :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode guardar numa array todos os que forem indo, fazendo a query com ORDER BY RAND() e na query fazer um SELECT WHERE id NOT IN ($suavariavel)